# Need to get the data of span using protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

I want to get the id=2504  which is in html span using protractor and display it in the console log. This id is generated dynamically so the id number can be different all the time.My code looks like :

```
<span class="link ng-binding" ng-click="openTrackId(mapFeedBack.reportId)">Your tracking number is 2504</span>
```

Please advise how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to extract numbers from a string. Look at below example code.

```
var id = element(by.css("span.link")).getText().then(function(text){
  return text.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the span text if the ID is the last thing written you can do

```
var textTokens = text.split(" ");
var Id = textTokens[textTokens.length - 1];
console.log(Id);
```

Using protractor you can do

```
element.all(by.tagName('span').get(0).getText().then(function(text){
    textTokens = text.split(" ");
    var Id = textTokens[textTokens - 1];
    console.log(Id);
});
```

Note if you have multiple spans you can put the above code in a loop and display the Id for each span element in your console.

```
element.all(by.tagName('span').count().then(function(spanCount){
    for (var i = 0; i < spanCount; i++){
        element.all(by.tagName('span').get(i).getText().then(function(text){
            textTokens = text.split(" ");
            var Id = textTokens[textTokens - 1];
            console.log(Id);
        });
    }
});
```